# How to use file path in excel name manager

Tags: excel, names

I created an excel document with references to other files. The table is pretty big and i would like to simplify the formulas of the cells. Hence I want to declare the file path in the names manager so that i can replace

```
='C:\Users\...\[worksheetname]tablename'!cells
```

with

```
=Name!cells
```

Is there any chance to get this working? It would be good, if the source file (the file, which the path belongs to) does not have to be opened in order to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT` to construct a string that refers to the cells, but this will still require the other workbook to be open. It would look like this:

`=INDIRECT(Name & "!Cells")`